# Why does my localhost webpage show text instead of Bootstrap NavBar? error 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, http-status-code-404

I've read through all the suggested questions, but nothing fits my issue.  I have been doing the One Month Rails.  I am trying to get Bootstrap changes to show on my Localhost:3000 site.  I can make some changes show up, but they are not rendered, look ugly and show up as text lists or bullets.  I started just trying a container, but that didn't work.  I tried a Navbar, but that shows up on the webpage as text, buttons are text, and there are some weird bullets too.  The font is not in Bootstrap font.  I have tried countless things on StackOverflow and other sites.  I don't know how to fix this and I fear all the things I tried has now messed it all up.

How can I get the Bootstrap components to show up on my localhost:3000 pinteresting page?  I am using Windows 7 Home Ed. and Chrome browser.

I have gone to Chrome's Developer Tools from the localhost page and found this:
http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/default.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/javascripts/default.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/stylesheets/default.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

My javascripts folder (from in Sublime) shows only application.js and pages.js.coffee

The stylesheets folder contains only application.css, bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss, and pages.css.scss.  The bootstrap_and_... is the one I was told to create through OneMonthRails.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure your following files have these lines, since I checked one of my projects and everything works perfectly there.

*(I prefer SCSS)*

**stylesheets/application.css**

```
/*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

**stylesheets/framework_and_override.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.1'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```